# Cannot see dash 14.04, 16.04

Tags: 14.04, unity, 16.04, launcher, unity-dash

Tried to install 16.04 today and ran into the problem of not being able to see the dash when I click the icon.

Reinstalled, then installed 14.04. Same issue. Things I've tried in 14.04:

- [alt]+[f2] , then [unity] to restart unity
- Reinstalling dash
- Reinstalling unity lens
- few other things sorry i can't remember

This is what it looks like.

[image: Screenshot]

If I click somewhere on screen I can open an application as if the menu opens but does not appear.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Try using low graphics mode, may be a driver or compiz issue.

To enable low graphics mode, go into a terminal and type:

wget -O ~/.config/upstart/lowgfx.conf http://pastebin.com/raw/RPaPPida

This will download a configuration file off the internet, and output it to the directory specified.  After you are done, reboot your computer, and see if this has worked.

[Source](https://insights.ubuntu.com/2016/09/19/low-graphics-mode-in-unity-7/)

Comment: Thanks. I had already tried that. I installed the gnome shell from the software center. Rebooted and selected it from the login page. It works. I will try KDE next. For some reason unity did not install the dash right. Should I mark this as solved?

Comment: I don't know, the issue you had hasn't been solved, but you found a workaround, I'd leave it open